# Bootstrap tabs not showing content after click

Tags: jquery, wordpress, twitter-bootstrap, bootstrap-4, tabs

I can't seem to get tabs to work properly on my site. http://mysocalled90sband.com/test

When the page loads, I can see the content under the first tab but when I switch to the second tab all content disappears. Switching back to the first tab shows no content until reload.

This code seems to work elsewhere so I think it must be something not loading properly on my site. jQuery seems to be loading fine (via WordPress) and so is the bootstrap js file (3.3.7). Smooth scrolling with a custom script file and various plug-ins are using jQuery alright on the main page. I've tried deactivating plugins running on other pages of the site but no luck there. Any ideas?

```
<ul class="nav nav-tabs nav-justified">
  <li class="active"><a data-toggle="tab" href="#menu1">Menu 1</a></li>
  <li><a data-toggle="tab" href="#menu2">Menu 2</a></li>
</ul>

<div class="tab-content">
  <div id="menu1" class="tab-pane fade in active">
    <h3>Menu 1</h3>
    <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit, sed do eiusmod tempor incididunt ut labore et dolore magna aliqua.</p>
  </div>
  <div id="menu2" class="tab-pane fade">
    <h3>Menu 2</h3>
    <p>Ut enim ad minim veniam, quis nostrud exercitation ullamco laboris nisi ut aliquip ex ea commodo consequat.</p>
  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: It works for me ? ....

Comment: @Tomm Are you saying the tabs on http://mysocalled90sband.com/test work for you?

Comment: Yes everything works perfectly fine

Comment: @Tomm I'm not seeing them work on any machine in the building... You're actually seeing the Lorem ipsum content showing under both Menu 1 and Menu 2?

Comment: Ohh like that no i only see that under Menu 1, you question is a bit unclear everything worked on the website exept for menu 2

Comment: You are using 2 versions of  bootstrap.js 3.3.7 and 3.3.5 through a plugin called booking. May be this is causing the issue. Try to remove one of them

Comment: @RajanBenipuri Good call. The booking plugin has the option for me to disable it from loading its version of bootstrap so I turned that on. Unfortunately, that didn't seem to fix the tabs on the test page though :(

Comment: the error is in your jquery function. You are removing the active class there as click event but never adding the active class to any of the .fade classes.

Comment: @RajanBenipuri Where would I look to edit that? Is that within the bootstrap js?

Comment: @RajanBenipuri. OK. I think I see what's happening here. My custom script for allowing the smooth scrolling for the nav section on the main page is interfering with the tabs since the tabs are also within a "nav" class.

Answer (score 1):

@RajanBeipuri led me to the solution. Thanks.

I had a custom script to allow for smooth scrolling on the main navigation on the home page.

```
function scrollNav() {
  $('.nav a').click(function(){  
    //Toggle Class
    $(".active").removeClass("active");      
    $(this).closest('li').addClass("active");
    var theClass = $(this).attr("class");
    $('.'+theClass).parent('li').addClass('active');
    //Animate
    $('html, body').stop().animate({
        scrollTop: $( $(this).attr('href') ).offset().top - 115
    }, 1000);
    return false;
  });
  $('.scrollTop a').scrollTop();
}
scrollNav();
```

This script was interfering with the tabs since they are also within a nav class. The solution was to add a class to my main navigation on the site and adjust the above script accordingly.